# Two Shell Script instance while calling through cron job

Tags: bash, cron

I have one simple script which echoes value of for loop.
I am calling same using a cron job and I ran grep command it shows two instances.

**Script::**

```
 #!/bin/bash
 for i in {1..999999}
 do
  echo "Welcome $i times"
 done
```

**Cron Command::**

```
* * * * * /home/amit/Desktop/crontest/test.sh > /home/amit/Desktop/crontest/null 2 >&1.
```

**ps Grep command::**

```
$ ps -ef | grep test

amit 5853  5852  0 23:28 ?  00:00:00 /bin/sh -c /home/amit/Desktop/crontest/test.sh > /home/amit/Desktop/crontest/null 2>&1
amit 5854  5853 99 23:28 ?  00:00:07 /bin/bash /home/amit/Desktop/crontest/test.sh 2
```

**My question is::**

It's really a two instance or it just a way how cron job run.

Comment: BTW, `2 >&1` is **not at all the same thing** as `2>&1`. Whitespace, or lack thereof, matters.

Comment: ...also, `"welcome $I times"` won't exactly work with a variable named `i` rather than `I`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cron implicitly runs the line given with `sh -c`.

If that line starts another shell (without recognizing it as the only command to run and implicitly making it an `exec` operation, an optimization some but not all shells will implicitly perform), then yes, you have two shells.

---

To have your first shell `exec` the second one, replacing its image in memory and inheriting its PID, consider using the following line in your cron job:

```
exec /home/amit/Desktop/crontest/test.sh >/home/amit/Desktop/crontest/null 2>&1
```

Comment: Cron implicitly runs the line given with sh -c.

If that line starts another shell, then yes, you have two shells.                    It means there are two process running parallel.

Comment: Eh, only sorta. If one is doing nothing but waiting for the other to exit, that's not very parallel. (BTW, when you quote something I said, could you put quotation marks around it?)

Comment: thanks @charles and Sure will follow your suggestion.